# c# Regex is number of length and allow whitespaces and dots

Tags: c#, regex

*To make it clear, this is just part of what my Input string can be, therefor its important the regex work as a bool, since I only wanna change the input if it looks like v1 & v2.*

Got a string input that can be writtin like this.

*(Just an example, it's not ip adresses I'm working with)*

```
string v1 => "192.168.0.1"

string v2 => "192 168 0 1"

string v3 => "19216801"
```

I have to rewrite the first 2 versions into version 3

Im thinking something like this.

```
version 1 
If input is of lenght X and only contains numbers and dots 
Then Replace(".", "").

version 2 
If input is of lenght x and only contains numbers and whitespaces 
Then Replace(" ", "").
```

How would it look in a more precise regex?

```
    3 numbers and (1 dot or whitespace) 
and 3 numbers and (1 dot or whitespace) 
and 1 number and (1 dot or whitespace) 
and 1 number
```

Comment: If you really only require what you shown in your example, regular expressions seem overkill (other then for learning purposes).

Comment: Yes I know, but the above is just part of what I can get in my input string, therefor I'm hoping for a simple regex solution, especially for the precise regex in the last part of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this expression

```
^(\d{3})[. ](\d{3})[. ](\d)[. ](\d)$
```

and replace with

```
$1$2$3$4
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vm4n)

`^` anchors on the start of the string

`$` anchors on the end of the string

`\d{3}` matches 3 digits (accordingly `\d` matches one digit)

`[. ]` is a character class matching either a dot or a space.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will return only numbers from any string

```
 public string ExtractNumbers(string expr)
        {
            return string.Join(null, System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(expr, "[^\\d]"));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but this don't work as a if then and would give me problems with other type of input strings. I updated my question to make it more clear.